# How do I fix this type inference in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript error I need to fix. This is declared in the script earlier:

```
protected suggestedServicesDict: { [id: number]: { [id: number]: { weight: number } } } = {}
```

then a for loop is used to attempt to loop through the collection

```
for (var categoryId in this.suggestedServicesDict) {
```

This results in the categoryId being inferred as a string not a number. Which later causes validation error because another function is expecting a number.
here later it is used in the suggestedCategory:

```
var suggestedCategory = { CategoryId: categoryId, Name: category.Name, AverageWeight: 0, Services: [] };
```

Here it is causing the suggestedCategory CategoryId to  be a string.

I don't seem to be able to successfully declare this as a number instead of allowing it to be inferred, I have tried a number of things, that have not worked.

Can any one tell me how to ensure that the categoryId is a number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While indexable types support numbers as keys, that only applies to adding/setting a value for a key:

```
let a = 3;
let o = {} as { [num: number]: string };

o[a] = "three";
```

But in javascript the keys are always strings, so the above code will actually create the following object:

```
{
    "3": "three"
}
```

If you know that your keys are string representation of numbers then you can use `Number` to get the number value:

```
for (let categoryId in this.suggestedServicesDict) {
    let idNumber = Number(categoryId);
    let value = this.suggestedServicesDict[idNumber]; // or [categoryId]
    ...
}
```